# Declaring array in C++ like array[1-00] by mistake but still code works, output is incorrect?

Tags: c++, arrays, syntax, declaration

When i declare array as array[1-00] by mistake i didn't get the right answer. But when i change it to normal declaration like array[100] i clear all the test cases.
Can anyone provide any explanation for this type of problem?
Please.

Comment: `00` is zero, in the octal representation. `1-00` is the same as `1-0`.

Comment: Why did you even expect that it could still work?

Comment: @molbdnilo -- fun fact: `0` is also octal.

Comment: @SkryptX i do a problem on hackerrank and it compiled and work, but only the answers are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared the array with a size of 1.

```
int arr[100]; //100 elements
int arr2[1]; //1 element
int arr3[1-00] // 1 - 0 = 1 element
```

accessing elements outside the array is undefined behavior, which means that the compiler can do whatever it wants.
Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) for more information about undefined behavior.